# Animated sprite one time and disapear

Tags: android, andengine, sprite, animated

```
this.MyAnimatedSprite.animate(50, 0);
 this.MyAnimatedSprite.setVisibility(false);
```

I am new to AndEngine and I want to animate whole AnimatedSprite once and let it disappear. In my code it only animates and stops but does not disappear, if I do setVisible(false).
It does not show animation even once.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by turning the visibility false after the animation is done.

```
 this.MyAnimatedSprite.animate(50,  0, new IAnimationListener () {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {

    this.MyAnimatedSprite.setVisibile(false);   
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStarted(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
            int pInitialLoopCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationFrameChanged(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
            int pOldFrameIndex, int pNewFrameIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationLoopFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
            int pRemainingLoopCount, int pInitialLoopCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }});
```

Comment: I had Edited the changes,I had tried it just now and it works.Thanks